# Cisco switch: how to copy a whole file (or part) to access-list?

Tags: acl, cisco

need help: I've found how to copy file with ACL rules to a switch as a file. But I can't figure out how to permit the data of my file to access-list. 
Does anybody know how can I do it?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
copy flash:filename running-config
```

Will **merge** the file you have copied to the switches 'flash' filesystem into the running configuration.